# Google Analytics - Event Goal Conversions not tracking

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to implement google analytics and I'm running into a problem where the tracking beacons are being sent, and the conversion goals are not being recorded.  What I'm trying to do is show a modal and record whether the modal is submitted or closed.  The goal setup I'm using is this:

```
Category: SignUp
Action: Newsletter
Label: Manual
Value: GreaterThan 1
```

These are the two things I've tried for the analytics code:

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'MyAccountNumber']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'MyDomainName']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  function _trackEvent(category, action, label, value, nonInteraction){
    nonInteraction = nonInteraction || false;
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label, parseInt(value), nonInteraction]);
  };
```

And this

```
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'MyAccountNumber', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  function _trackEvent(category, action, label, value){
    ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, value);
  };
```

I am calling _track event as such:

```
_trackEvent('SignUp', 'Newsletter', label, 0);

$('#modalSubmit').click(function() {
  _trackEvent('SignUp', 'Newsletter', 'Manual', 1);
});
```

As I previously said, the tracking beacons are being sent, but there is no data showing up in the Reporting section.  The dates for the report are set to yesterday through tomorrow.  Also, if I'm not handling the abandonment rate correctly, what is the correct way to handle this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the Classic Analytics or Universal Analytics tracker? Is data being sent correctly to your reports? Events setup looks fine.

Comment: @carlodurso Is there a difference in the server setup between the two?  I tried both client-side scripts, and neither seemed to make a difference.  The tracking script I get from the admin tab gives me the Universal Analytics script.

Comment: you should only use the universal tracker. It's more accurate. Make sure you're receiving data then troubleshoot events accordingly.

Comment: @carlodurso OK, I've been using only the universal tracker for the last hour.  I still don't have any data.  Ideas?

Comment: Google Analytics generally updates your reports every 24 hours, so it can take at least that long for data to appear in your account after you first install the tracking code. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009219?hl=en

Comment: @carlodurso In that case, is there any way to do testing to make sure that my tracking codes are correct?  Or can I only test once every 24 hours?  Specifically I'm doing event tracking, and want to make sure I implemented conversion rates correctly.

Comment: Actually, where you get the tracking code you should see the status. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en

Comment: You can check in your real-time reports to see if the event shows up. You can see it right away if all is working, so no need to wait 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use the universal tracker. It's more accurate.

Make sure you're receiving data then troubleshoot events accordingly. You can check the tracking code status in the Admin section of GA: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en

Google Analytics generally updates your reports every 24 hours, so it can take at least that long for data to appear in your account after you first install the tracking code: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009219?hl=en